# Display Multiple Mongoose Models on one results page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am needing to display Multiple Mongoose Models on one results page. Here is my current code to get the results page. I have models set up for "Cards" and "Beliefs" but I cannot figure out the syntax to display both. Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
app.get("/profile", function(req, res){
    Cards.find({ "author.username": req.user.username }, function(err, author){
    Beliefs.find({"author.username": req.user.username }, function(err, author){
    if (err){
    console.log(err);
     } else { 
res.render("done.ejs", {Beliefs: author, Cards: author, currentUser: req.user});
}
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different variable names for author. `Belief`'s callback function argument `author` is overlapping the `author` you received from `Cards` model. Something like beliefsAuthor and cardsAuthor should do.